# OpenGL Scene - Iphone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

Question: why would an OpenGL scene render upside down in portrait mode but right-side up in landscape and visa-versa?

If I create a view matrix with UPx = 0, UPy = 0, UPz = 1 I get my viewport upside down in portrait mode and right-side up in landscape.

If I create a view matrix with UPx = 0, UPy = 0, UPz = -1 I get my viewport right-side up in portrait mode and upside down in landscape.

Should I be looking at other functions other than where I create my LookAt and Perspective matrices?

Comment: How do you construct your projection matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Got it - my FOVY angle was in degrees for Android - but GLKit for IOS requires radians. Dohhh.